# How to use noexcept operator correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

I've implemented a smart pointer that stores an object of type T with proxy function that calls the internal object's methods:

```
template <class Function, class ...Args, class ...Params> 
inline bool call( Function (T::*function)(Args...) const, Params&& ...args ) const noexcept( noexcept( function ));
```

But I have found a strange problem - when an std::exception is generated in a member function, the program is terminated, even though the proxy function is called within a try block. So my question is: is it a correct way to use noexcept operator, and if not, how should I use it in this case?

Comment: What's wrong with the smart pointers already in C++11 and/or `std::function`?

Comment: It uses copy on write in some special cases. And it makes all calls to the stored object thread safe.

Comment: See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec), particularly "If a function marked `noexcept` allows an uncaught exception to escape at runtime, `std::terminate` is called immediately. "

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but neither T::function, nor this proxy call is marked noexcept, as far as I understand. I thought that noexcept operator would detect that member function can throw, cause it is not marked noexcept..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per C++11 §5.3.7/1:

> The `noexcept` operator determines whether the evaluation of its operand, which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), can throw an exception (15.1).

Evaluating the expression `(function)` cannot throw an exception, so `noexcept(function)` evaluates to `true`. Note that this is *not* the same as evaluating the expression `(*function)(std::forward<Params>(args)...)`, `noexcept((*function)(std::forward<Params>(args)...))` would certainly evaluate to `false`, since the member function pointer is not qualified `noexcept`.

`noexcept` is a qualification on function pointer types like `const`. Since the function pointer type `call` accepts is NOT `noexcept`-qualified, that complicated `noexcept(noexcept(...))` will always evaluate as `noexcept(false)`.

EDIT: The below is incorrect, it's not possible to overload purely on the basis of `noexcept` qualification of a function pointer since "An *exception-specification* is not considered part of a function’s type." (§15.4/13)

<s>If you want `call` to be `noexcept` when given a `noexcept`-qualified member function pointer, you need to provide an overload `call(R (T::*)() const noexcept, ...)`.</s>

Comment: Thanks for you answer! So should I use it like this - 

    noexcept( noexcept( *function(std::forward<Params>(args)...))
?

Comment: @PavelDavydov Yep, that's correct. It really gets fun when you have the exact same expression in the `noexcept` clause, in the trailing return type, and in the function body ;) `auto foo(...) -> decltype(expr) noexcept(noexcept(expr)) { return expr; }`

Comment: Looks cool =). I was thinking for a while how to make it work with functions that have a return type different from bool, now I know it, thanks!

Comment: @PavelDavydov Clarified in my answer that for your specific case, `call` can never be `noexcept`.

Comment: @PavelDavydov Clarified again that I am a dirty lying liar and it's not possible to overload on `noexcept` alone.