# noexcept operator used on function object always yields true

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, noexcept

I ran into this by accident, while playing around with the `noexcept` operator when trying to implement my own version of `std::visit` for educational purposes. This is the code with only the relevant parts:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Ts>
struct visitor : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<typename... Ts>
visitor(Ts...) -> visitor<Ts...>;

int main() {
    auto vis1 = visitor {
        [](int s) {
        },
        [](double s) {
        }
    };

    constexpr auto isNoExcept = noexcept(vis1);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isNoExcept << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

This always outputs `true` for me (gcc and clang).

I have 2 questions:

1. How can the `noexcept` operator even be applied when there are multiple `operator()`s, since some might be `noexcept`, while others are not? How can there be one answer? What exactly happens here?
2. Why does this return `true`, even though none of the lambdas are declared `noexcept`?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150625/how-to-use-noexcept-operator-correctly help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `noexcept(vis1)` the expression you're checking is `vis1`. The evaluation of this expression can't possibly throw an exception, because it doesn't do anything. So this returns `true` regardless of the exception specification on any of the functions in the overload set defined by `vis1`.

However, if you write `noexcept(vis1(42))`, then you are checking whether evaluating the expression `vis1(42)` might throw an exception. Since the overload taking an `int` is not marked `noexcept`, the evaluation may indeed throw an exception, and this returns `false`.

---

To answer your specific question,

> How can the `noexcept` operator even be applied when there are multiple `operator()`s?

You're not supposed to apply the `noexcept` operator on all the `operator()`s at once, but only one specific `operator()` at a time as I showed above, and in that case, the compiler simply checks whether the overload that would be picked is marked `noexcept` or not.

Comment: Of course, classic case of couldn't see the forest for the trees! Like `decltype(vis1)` vs `decltype(vis1(42))`. Thanks :-) So if I want to make the `noexcept`ness of my function dependent on the `noexcept`ness of ALL the `operator()`s in the passed in visitor, I'll have to fold over the conjunction of the individual `noexcept`s.